# How much material can be changed between an accepted manuscript and "camera ready?"

Tags: publications

After a paper has been accepted, other than the reviewers' suggestions, how much content can be changed before the camera-ready version is resubmitted?  Is there a general guideline? Thanks!

Comment: I vote for reopening, there is a huge difference between "between peer review and final submission" and "between accept and 'camera ready'.

Comment: @PeterJansson: I agree with aeismail's closing: the linked question actually considers that the paper has been accepted, and I'm not entirely sure of the difference between camera-ready and final submission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my (very limited) experience in CS, a lot (if its a conference), *but only if you are somehow improving the paper* - you can't obviously publish after removing key results that caused the acceptance in the first place!

*Anecdote:* My first publication happened after I was able to solve one of the 3 open problems posed at the end of an accepted paper by my advisor - this caused the entire paper to be re-written in terms of the more generalized result, and it did not go through any further reviews (only an informal mail from my advisor to the editors outlining what we did!)

Comment: Are you allowed to exceed the page limit?